# Get cell item which matches string

Tags: matlab

I have the following code:

```
subDir = dir(frames_dir); 
isub = [subDir(:).isdir];
nameSubFolds = {subDir(isub).name}';
```

I'd like to only choose items in "nameSubFolds" which contain the string "2017", with any characters after it (so, "2017*"). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the builtin regular expressions of `dir`:

```
subDir = dir([frames_dir '/*2017*']);
isub = [subDir(:).isdir];
nameSubFolds = {subDir(isub).name}';
```